# Create Rest call to server

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to write a command in C# in order to get a session cookie from the server.

for example from command line I'm executing the next line:

```
curl -i http://localhost:9999/session -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email": "user", "password": "1234"}'


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 03 Jan 2013 15:52:36 GMT
Content-Length: 30
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AQqLLtFz%2FgnzPGCbljObyxKH9.U%2Fm1nVX%2BHdE1ZFo0zNK5hJalLylIBh%2FoQ1igUycAQAE; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Now I'm trying to create the same request in C#

```
string session = "session/";
string server_url = "http://15.185.117.39:3000/";
string email = "user";
string pass = "1234";
string urlToUSe = string.Format("{0}{1}", server_url, session);

HttpWebRequest httpWebR = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToUSe);
httpWebR.Method = "POST";
httpWebR.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
httpWebR.ContentType = "application/json";

HttpWebResponse response;
response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebR.GetResponse();
```

But when I'm running this code, I'm getting the 401 error on the last line.

What went wrong ?

thanks !

Comment: Is it the actual code? I don't see any code that triggers the request, so I think you missed some part of the code.

Comment: oops, right, I've copied here the wrong line - now it has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

> What went wrong ?

Can't you see in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)? The `NetworkCredential` you're providing is not the same as posting a JSON string with an e-mail address and username, it:

> [Provides credentials for password-based authentication schemes such as basic, digest, NTLM, and Kerberos authentication.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx).

You need to post the data using the HttpWebRequest. How to do so is described in [How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx):

```
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

Where you of course replace the appropriate values where required.

Also, you can use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is easier for posting data. It doesn't support cookies by default, but I've written a blog on [how to enable cookies for the `WebClient`](http://codecaster.nl/blog/2012/12/using-the-webclient-class-with-cookies/).

Comment: Hi There, I've tried your Stream solution, but still I got the 401 error from the server as a response... :(

Comment: But I do see that I'm getting a header from the server which contains a cookie... so may be I need to catch this WebException and to recover the cookie from out there ? and then each REST call I'll do, I'll use that cookie... sounds logical ?

Comment: @user301639 no, it is not logical you receive a 401 error. Are you sure you're posting the correct data? Compare a request made by a browser to a request made by your program using Fiddler, and see what differences there are.

Comment: The thing is that the "/session/" is a REST call with all the arguments I send, I cannot make it trough the browser.

Comment: @user301639 I meant the request you issue using curl.